# How to convert categorical string variables in Excel to numeric variables?

Tags: r, excel, dataset, rstudio, data-analysis

I am trying to analyze road collision data. I need to convert the categorical data into numeric data in Excel before I import it to RStudio, but I am not able to do it.

Excel file containing the sample data to be used:

[image: Excel file containing the sample data to be used]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, make sure to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code, so others can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, as I don't know which value you want to search with and which you want as the result, I have shown it taking the weather and returning the leftmost column.

You can change that as you need as I have used Index() with match().

[image]

So, based on the comment, all you need is left() to get the number, I have used find() to get the space just in case you have 2 or 3 digit numbers...

```
=LEFT(C3,FIND(" ",C3,1)-1)
```

C3 is the target cell, drag down as far as...

Comment: Thank you for answering. I want to change the "1 Fine" in the Weather column to just 1 and the "9 Unknown" to just 9 and do the same for the rest of the column.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. Are you able to explain the reasoning for the function?